# get rid of arrow tikzset

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I have a custom tikz set (below) which ends with an arrow if it is not enclosed.

```
\tikzset{
    partial ellipse/.style args={#1:#2:#3}{
        insert path={+ (#1:#3) arc (#1:#2:#3)}
    }
}
```

When it is used like this `\draw[blue,-latex](5in,5in)[partial ellipse=90:210:1in and .5in] -- (5in,5in)--cycle;`, it has no arrow. However when used like:

- `\draw[blue,-latex](5in,5in)[partial ellipse=90:210:1in and .5in] -- (5in,5in);`
- `\draw[blue,-latex](5in,5in)[partial ellipse=90:210:1in and .5in];`

It ends the line with an arrow. Is there a way to disable this?

Full Code Example:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns.meta,calc,hobby}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usepackage{pgfmath}

% I just included other packages i am using elsewhere in my document

\tikzset{
    partial ellipse/.style args={#1:#2:#3}{
        insert path={+ (#1:#3) arc (#1:#2:#3)}
    }
} 

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[blue,-latex](5in,5in)[partial ellipse=90:210:1in and .5in] -- (5in,5in)--cycle;

\draw[blue,-latex](8in,8in)[partial ellipse=90:210:1in and .5in];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `\tikzset` definition is fine, You are adding the arrow head using `-latex` that it does not show you when you close the path. Just use  `\draw[blue] ...`

Comment: OK, I wasn't sure what was causing it exactly.